# JDK and Applets

Tags: java, applet

I have a problem. I can't run applets because I using **JDK 13**.
We have a few hours at University with Applets so what I should do .? 
Delete JDK 13 and download older version or is it possible to run 2 versions of JDK on one PC.?

Please for serious answers.
**Thank You**

Comment: You can try to use [CherpJ](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cheerpj-applet-runner/bbmolahhldcbngedljfadjlognfaaein?hl=en).

Comment: A copy/paste comment I thought I'd have no more use for.. Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). **Note:** that was written *before* applets were deprecated and removed. So there is even less excuse now for teachers to use applets. Ask the teacher if it's OK to use a desktop class like `JFrame` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can install multiple versions of the JDK, but you have to switch between them, which can be messy depending on what environment you are using.

If you are using an IDE like IntelliJ or Eclipse, you can just go into the project settings and select the different JDK for the project.

If you are running your java apps through the command line you have to do a little bit more work depending on what operating system you are running.

Here are some examples I found: [Ubuntu](https://aboullaite.me/switching-between-java-versions-on-ubuntu-linux/), [MacOS](https://medium.com/@devkosal/switching-java-jdk-versions-on-macos-80bc868e686a), [Windows](https://blogs.oracle.com/pranav/switch-between-different-jdk-versions-in-windows)

Although you might have to do some more digging yourself :)

Comment: but if I using IDE NetBeans could I download 2 versions (apache and 8.2) and run JDK 13 on Apache NetBeans and JDK 8 on NetBeans 8.2 to run applets ?